# Error on Content Security Policy while testing for Clickjacking

Tags: penetration-test, content-security-policy, clickjacking

I was recently testing for Clickjacking and when I opened developer tools, I was warning

`Content Security Policy: Ignoring “'unsafe-inline'” within script-src or style-src: nonce-source or hash-source specified`

Do you guys think it is possible to bypass it, If yes can you share me the further information?

[image]

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This warning just means that a script was already explicitly trusted by `nonce-source` or `hash-source` and that the additional `unsafe-inline` makes no sense in this context - and thus will be ignored. The warning does not indicate that any bypass could be possible.